# Migrations vs Version Control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, rails-migrations

I'm currently learning Rails and building a blog app. I can't wrap my head around migrations. I'm assuming from what i've [read](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), that you can use migrations to add columns, tables to a database. But why is that important/ can that not be accomplished by version control?

I appreciate any feedback/guidance. I am pretty new to rails/ActiveRecord and so please bear with me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "version control"? A git repository certainly does not update the schema of a Postgresql database.

Comment: Hi @Thilo, I think I was simply confused from my interpretation of reading. 

Migrations directly deal with making changes with the db, where as version control is totally separate and refers to keeping track of commits when dealing with code. Am I in the ball park now?

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-migration-and-git

Comment: @Thilo thanks for the treehouse link! It's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations work for databases as a Git repo works for code.
It keeps track of the changes made to the database during the development of the app.

Without migrations, you would have to manually do all the changes on every device you share the code.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I guess a silly question and complete misunderstanding.

To confirm: 

Migrations = "version control for database"
Git = "Version control for code" ?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: That's right. It's a fair question and a concept that will truly help you in the future.

Comment: Well, "migrations" are defined by files that you want to keep in your source code repository. But they also have a result (such as tracking tables) as they are being applied to a database (which can happen automatically during deployment, that is a big part of the promise here).

Answer (score 1):

Migrations and version control are two entirely different things.  Migrations do not maintain states.  Migrations are a way of altering your database / model, and they do a lot more than 'add columns' as you said it.

Everyone should review [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) when getting started.

Version control doesn't just maintain your database structure.  Let's say you change your database, and views and controllers and decide, and then decide you only want to undo your database change.  Reverting your version control would undo all your changes.  That's bad I think